# text of left div to be center according to the contents of right div

Tags: html, css

I want the text of left div to be center of the div according to the contents of right div.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="" style="float:left">
        <p style="color: #222;margin-bottom: 0; text-align:center;">08:30 - 09:30</p>
    </div>
    <div class=" agenda_name" style=" float:right;">
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZX</p>
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

expected output is in the image.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: vertically or horizontally centered and mention your expected output

Comment: vertically and horizontally. both center.

Comment: Now check below answer.I hope It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` to the `div`
Add `margin: 0 auto` and `display:table` to `p` tag

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="">
    <p style="color: #222;margin-bottom: 0; margin: 0 auto; display:table;">08:30 - 09:30</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" agenda_name" style=" float:right;">
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZX</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below html and css code and **remove inline css float:left; and float:right** from you div.

```css
.section {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.row.content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.left_div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%; /* set width as per you needed */
}
.right_div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%; /* set width as per you needed */
}
.left_div > p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
   <div class="row content">
      <div class="left_div" style="">

        <p>08:30 - 09:30</p>
      </div>                
      <div class="right_div agenda_name" style="">  
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZX</p>
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>

        <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give heigth to both left and right divs. Set display:table to parent div and display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle; to child element of the left div to center vertically and horizandally

```css
.leftdiv,
.agenda_name {
  width: 50%;
  height: 152px;
}
.leftdiv {
  display: table;
}
.leftdiv p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftdiv" style="float:left">
    <p style="color: #222;margin-bottom: 0; text-align:center;">08:30 - 09:30</p>
  </div>
  <div class="agenda_name" style=" float:right;">
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZX</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="" style="float:left; height: 30%; width:50%;">
    <p style="color: #222;margin-bottom: 0; text-align:center; margin-top: 25%">08:30 - 09:30</p>
  </div>
  <div class=" agenda_name" style=" float: right;height: 30%;width:50%;">
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZX</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
    <p style="font-weight: 400;">XYZXYZ Xdssgg</p>
  </div>
</div>
```